# Ack not returning results in Vim in ubuntu

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04, ack

I'm using vim with ack in ubuntu. When searching with :Ack is not returning any result.
I had installed both ack-grep and ack.vim.

am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 3):

Ack.vim is [able to recognize](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/blob/master/plugin/ack.vim#L12) both `ack-grep` and `ack`. If none of those are in your `$PATH`, you can define the path to ack in your `~/.vimrc`, like this:

```
let g:ackprg="<custom-ack-path-goes-here> -H --nocolor --nogroup --column"
```

Answer (score 2):

we have to create a symlink for ack to work with vim

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ack-grep /usr/bin/ack
```